# R: Filter rows from a matrix if e.g. a certain value is present in any more left column than another certain value in a more right column?

Tags: r, subset

I have a matrix and would like to do the following:

1. Remove all rows containing "Z" more than once
2. Remove all rows containing at least two occurrences of "S" in direct neighbor columns
3. Remove all rows in which "2D" exists not only once and in which "1D" is not or not only once being present in a more left column (lower column number)

Here is a MWE with explanation:

```
x <- matrix(c(
            # Point 1:
            "Z", "1D", "Z", "S",  # Delete row because Z is present more than once.
            # Point 2:
            "S", "S", "Z", "1D", # Delete row because S is present at least twice and in columns following each other directly.
            "S", "Z", "S", "1D", # Ok because "S" is present multiple times but there is at least one column between the occurrences.
            # Point 3:
            "1D", "Z", "2D", "1D", # 1D is followed by a later "2D" which is correct, but another "1D" follows after "2D", so delete this row.
            "Z", "S", "2D", "S", # "2D" is present without a "1D" in a more left column, so delete this row.
            "2D", "1D", "Z", "S", # "2D" is present without a "1D" in a more left column, so delete this row.
            "1D", "Z", "S", "2D", # Valid row
            "1D", "2D", "S", "Z"), # Valid row 
             nrow = 8, byrow = TRUE)

# Possible solution for removing columns with multiple occurences of "Z"
require(matrixStats)
x <- x[!rowCounts(x, value = "Z")>1, ]
```

How can the second and third point be done?

Comment: In row 3 there is no "2D" value. Do you still want to keep it?

Comment: Yes please,  a  "1D" value without "2D" is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this custom function :

```
apply_rules <- function(y) {
  rule1 <- sum(grepl('Z', y)) > 1
  rule2 <- any(with(rle(grepl('S', y)), values & lengths > 1))
  d1 <- which(y == '1D')
  d2 <- which(y == '2D')
  rule3 <- length(d1) < 1 || any(d1 > d2)
  rule1 || rule2 || rule3
}

apply(x, 1, apply_rules)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

x[!apply(x, 1, apply_rules), ]

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "S"  "Z"  "S"  "1D"
#[2,] "1D" "Z"  "S"  "2D"
#[3,] "1D" "2D" "S"  "Z"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**
I didn't notice your comment that we could have a single `1D` in a row so I made some modifications and the output is just what you had expected:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  as_tibble(names_repair = 'unique') %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Sum_Z = sum(c_across(everything()) == "Z"), 
         col = paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4), 
         SS_exist = grepl("S{2,}", col),
         both_1D_2D = grepl("1D", col) & grepl("2D", col),
         `1D after 2D` = grepl("2D1D", col),
         `1D` = grepl("1D", col)) %>%
  filter(Sum_Z <= 1, !SS_exist, `1D`, !`1D after 2D`, both_1D_2D || `1D`) %>%
  select(V1:V4) %>%
  as.matrix(dimnames = NULL)


     V1   V2   V3  V4  
[1,] "S"  "Z"  "S" "1D"
[2,] "1D" "Z"  "S" "2D"
[3,] "1D" "2D" "S" "Z"
```

Comment: Two minor corrections suggested.  use of `names_repair` argument and use `Sum_Z <= 1` in order to keep those rows without `Z` too.  However, that'll override with other `OR` conditions

Comment: Thank you very much dear @AnilGoyal , I really appreciate your valuable recommendations.